# Write a single column of an xlsx file to csv using python xlrd

Tags: python, csv, xlrd

I am 99% of the way there...

```
def xl_to_csv(xl_file):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(xl_file)
    sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    output = 'output.csv'
    op = open(output, 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(op, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
        part_number = sh.cell(rownum,1)
        #wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))  #writes entire row
        wr.writerow(part_number)
    op.close()
```

using `wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))` I can write the entire row from the Excel file to a CSV, but there are like 150 columns and I only want one of them.  So, I'm grabbing the one column that I want using `part_number = sh.cell(rownum,1)`, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct to just write this variable out to a CSV file.

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 61, in <module>
    xl_to_csv(latest_file)
  File "test.py", line 32, in xl_to_csv
    wr.writerow(part_number)
_csv.Error: sequence expected
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you currently have? If you are encountering errors, please add those errors to your question. Also, which column (first or second) are you trying to get?

Comment: Something to note: a single column csv file (or any other delimiter) is simply a text file.  No quoting needed.  No delimiters will be used.  (Well, one caveat.  This is true as long as you have no multiline strings.)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski That's a good point... I was planning on adding a second field - but I may have ADD those first before I test the output...

Comment: `wr.writerow([part_number.value])` could be a fix.

Comment: @Abdou - thank you!  the `.value` is what I needed to append Paulo's answer below.

Comment: @BrianPowell:  Since you may be adding more fields I posted an answer that will let you add fields easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
wr.writerow([part_number.value])
```

The argument must be a list-like object.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest fix is to throw your `partnum` in a `list` (and as per Abdou you need to add `.value` to get the value out of a cell):

```
for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
    part_number = sh.cell(rownum,1).value  # added '.value' to get value from cell
    wr.writerow([part_number]) # added brackets to give writerow the list it wants
```

More generally, you can use a list comprehension to grab the columns you want:

```
cols = [1, 8, 110]
for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
    wr.writerow([sh.cell(rownum, colnum).value for colnum in cols])
```